What is the story of Manikarnika Ghat of Kashi?
As far as I know, two ghats are very famous in Kashi. One is Dashaswamedha Ghat and another is Manikarnika Ghat. In Dashaswamedha Ghat, Brahma performed 10 horse sacrifices (link).
What is the story behind Manikarnika Ghat? I heard that Parvati's earring fell on this place. Is this true? Is there any reference?

Haven't come across that exact story of Parvati's earrings falling at this place. There's another version in the Skanda Purana where Lord Shiva's earring fell at this place and he named it Manikarnika: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423764.html

@HariHara Please write it as an answer. I will accept. I was not sure whose earring it was. So the version you said is the right one. Please write it as an answer.

As per Skanda-Purana Kāśī-khaṇḍa Chapter 26, when Lord Shiva was pleased with the penance of Lord Vishnu at this place, his gemstead ear-ring fell here and he personally named it Manikarnika.

श्रीशिव उवाच ।
एवमस्तु हृषीकेश यत्त्वयोक्तं जनार्दन ।
अन्यं वरं प्रयच्छामि तमाकर्णय सुव्रत ॥ ६१ ॥

Śrīśiva said: O Hṛṣīkeśa, O Janārdana, let everything turn out as said
by you. I shall grant you another boon. Listen to it, O excellent one
of noble vows.
त्वदीयस्यास्य तपसो महोपचय दर्शनात् ।
यन्मयांदोलितो मौलिरहिश्रवणभूषणः ॥ ६२ ॥
तदांदोलनतः कर्णात्पपात मणिकर्णिका ।
मणिभिः खचिता रम्या ततोऽस्तु मणिकर्णिका ॥ ६३ ॥

On seeing the steady increase of this penance of yours, I shook my
head having serpents. As a result of that movement, my gemset earring
fell down. It was set with jewels and was beautiful in appearance. Let
this (sacred expanse of water) be named Maṇikarṇikā.
चक्रपुष्करिणी तीर्थं पुराख्यातमिदं शुभम् ।
त्वया चक्रेण खननाच्छंखचक्रगदाधर ॥ ६४ ॥
मम कर्णात्पपातेयं यदा च मणिकर्णिका ।
तदाप्रभृति लोकेऽत्र ख्यातास्तु मणिकर्णिका ॥ ६५ ॥

This splendid sacred place had become well known as Cakrapuṣkariṇī
Tīrtha formerly, because it was dug out by means of your discus, O
Lord holding the conch, discus and mace. Let it become famous by the
name Maṇikarṇikā here in this world, ever since the time when the
gemset earring fell into it from my ear.
श्रीविष्णुरुवाच ।
मुक्ताकुंडलपातेन तवाद्रितनयाप्रिय ।
तीर्थानां परमं तीर्थं मुक्तिक्षेत्रमिहास्तु वै ॥ ६६ ॥

Śrīviṣṇu said: O Lord, O beloved of the Daughter of the Mountain, by
virtue of the dropping of your pearl earring here, let this holy spot
become the greatest of all holy spots that are salvation- granting
holy places.
काशतेऽत्र यतो ज्योतिस्तदनाख्येयमीश्वरः ।
अतो नामापरं चास्तु काशीति प्रथितं विभो ॥ ६७ ॥

O mighty Lord, since that brilliance which cannot be adequately
described, shines here, let another name ‘Kāśī’ be well-known for it.

